# Syntax error when passing dynamic value to sql query in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, database, postgresql

I am trying to pass dynamic value to sql query in node js, but all im getting is syntax error code: '42601', error: syntax error at or near ")"
Can someone help me figure it out what i am doing wrong ?

```
app.post("/message", async (req, res) => {
  const { todos } = await client.query(
    `INSERT INTO todo (todo) VALUES (${req.body.todos})`
  );
  return res.status(201).json(todos);
});
```

Comment: what does req.body.todos look like

Comment: array with entries from an input, there is values. But the error is syntax as it stated

Comment: are you allowed queries like that. shouldnt be something like `INSERT INTO todo (todo) VALUES (todoValue)`. btw what package use for postgres in node

Comment: Yes thats what im trying to do, to pass the req.body.todos which is the entire from an input, but all i got is syntax error

Comment: @cmgchess im a beginner and this is my very first full stack project

Comment: can you console log req.body.todos and show what you get

Comment: asdsd,sadsds line 23 , console.log(req.body.todos + " line 23");

Comment: Check your database log on a single user test system to see what's actually arriving at the database!